# sqlite force close after opening database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My databases (information to display on a table) are connected to buttons. When they are clicked, the table should show info. The database works, but this is the catcher: It works when I had info already entered from testing. But the database crashes if their is nothing to load. Here is the code:

```
rentD.open();
Log.d(TAG, "OPENING RENT DATABASE...");
String rentData = rentD.getData();
billAmount.setText("Total: " + nf.format(rentD.getAmountTotal()));
Log.d(TAG, "CLOSING RENT DATABASE...");
rentD.close();
Log.d(TAG, "RENT DATABASE CLOSED");
dataResults.setText(rentData);
```

So every time I click the RENT button, I get a forced close. After further looking, The problem I found have to do with:

```
billAmount... nf.format(rentD.getAmountTotal()));
```

which displays a the amount in money format. So if I replace "rentD.getAmountTotal()" with a String variable, the database works perfectly. Here is the error I recieved from LogCat:

```
10-26 23:53:40.764: DEBUG/DEBUG(14999): OPENING RENT DATABASE...
10-26 23:53:40.764: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(14999): Shutting down VM
10-26 23:53:40.764: WARN/dalvikvm(14999): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught    exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
```

Again, the problem seems to be passing data that doesn't exist yet into the textview.
My end result is to have the program start with no data in it so the user can get to the activities that will populate the table. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is variable `nf` and what does it do?

Comment: nf is just a NumberFormatter (currency).

Comment: @androidnoob I tried a try/catch/finally, got it work so I could enter data from another activity, but it changed how my database acts unfavorably...

Comment: Is there a stacktrace after the `thread exiting with uncaught exception` part in logcat? Also, the code of the class behind the `rentD` variable would help.

Comment: Can you post your full code and logcat output?

Comment: @PhilippReichart ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6215): at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:263)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6215):at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6215): java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:356)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6215): com.###.###.RentSQLHelper.getAmountTotal(RentSQLHelper.java:95)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6215):at com.###.###.finActivity$3.onClick(finActivity.java:207)

Comment: @PhilippReichart My database is the same model from TheNewBoston tutorials minus the editing entries. I have 2 form Activities (save & delete) that opens and closes RentSQLHelper. The buttons are on my main Activity. It opens, retrieves all data, prints textviews (one for table, the other for total), then closes.

Comment: Somewhere in `RentSQLHelper.getAmountTotal()` you pass a `null` value to `Double.valueOf()`.

Comment: @PhilippReichart public double getAmountTotal(){
  Cursor cursor = ourRDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(RENT_AMOUNT) FROM rentTable", null);
  if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
  cc = Double.valueOf(cursor.getString(0));
  }
  dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
  dFormat.format(cc);
  return cc;
 }

Comment: @PhilippReichart Thank you for the answer. I believe I dont know exactly where to apply your suggestion. Above is my getAmountTotal().

Comment: Next time, please add the code to your question, it's much easier to read :) As for your problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, I would suggest you drop the `DecimalFormat` from `getAmountTotal()` because it does nothing useful (you're not using the return value of `format()`), and use this instead:

```
public double getAmountTotal() {
    Cursor cursor = ourRDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(RENT_AMOUNT) FROM rentTable", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return cursor.getDouble(0);
    } else {
        return 0; // or another default value of your choice
    }
}
```